# Number of fixed points of a meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

I would like to know whether a meromorphic function on the whole complex plane with at most one pole can have infinitely many fixed points or not. 
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How about $\sin z+z$?

Comment: @Shalop Note that $\sin(z)+z$ has no poles. The statement of this post requires a function with at most one pole.

Answer (score 0):

**An answer to your question may be that the two situations can occur.**

Consider the meromorphic function:
$$f(z)=\frac{\cos(z)}{z}+z.$$

Note that $z_{0}=0$ is a pole of degree 1 of $f$, indeed:
$$f(z)=\frac{\cos(z)}{z}+z=\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{z^{2n}}{n!}+z=\frac{1}{z}+z+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{z^{2n}}{n!}.$$

Also, note that $f$ has infinitely many fixed points because, in particular, the points of the form:
$$z=\pi n -\frac{\pi}{2}  \qquad \mbox{ for each }n\in \mathbb{Z}$$
are fixed points of $f$. So, **$f$ is a function that satisfies your requirements and has infinitely many fixed points**.

For other hand, consider $g(z)=\frac{1}{z}$, clearly $g$ has a pole in $z_{0}=0$ of degree 1, but **$g$ have not  infinitely many fixed points**.